# Build react project based on branch name environment variables

Tags: reactjs, jenkins, environment-variables, dockerfile

In my project I have many git branch names (dev, test, stage ....) and I am building my React app using Docker, and using Jenkins to deploy it.

What I want is to specify my REACT_APP_BASE_URL based on my current branch name because I have several base URLs, for example (https://abc.dev.example, https://abc.test.example ..), and I want to run the matched name.

What I did was:

- create .env.dev : 
  REACT_APP_BASE_URL= 'https://abc.dev.example'
- create .env.production : 
  REACT_APP_BASE_URL= 'https://abc.production.example'
- create .env.test : 
  REACT_APP_BASE_URL= 'https://abc.test.example'
- npm install env-cmd --save

---

My script:

```
"start": "env-cmd -f .env.dev react-app-rewired start",
"build": "react-app-rewired build",
"build:develop": "env-cmd -f .env.dev react-app-rewired build",
"build:test": "env-cmd -f .env.test react-app-rewired build",
"build:demo": "env-cmd -f .env.demo react-app-rewired build",
```

---

It's always looking for the url on `.env.production` file for all branches because it considers the production during the build process, so how can I solve that?
Any ideas?